# Cannot display value from Mongodb on my Jade page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I have the following route :

```
app.get('/dashboard', passportConf.isAuthenticated, userController.getBoardsCount,userController.getSharedBoardsCount, userController.getBoards);
```

This is the middleware code I'm using to get my values from MongoDB:

```
exports.getBoardsCount = function(req, res, next) {
    var count = 0;
    Room.count({
        "owner": req.user._id
    }, function(err, count) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (count) {
            req.count = count;
        }
        next();
        console.log(count);
    })
};

exports.getSharedBoardsCount = function(req, res, next) {
    var sharedBoards = 0;
    Room.count({
        $and: [{"owner": {$ne: req.user._id}},{ users : req.user._id}]
    }, function(err, sharedBoards) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (sharedBoards) {
            req.sharedBoards = sharedBoards;
        }
        next();
        console.log(sharedBoards);
    })
};
```

I can display the `count` on my jade file by using `#{count}`, but the `sharedBoards` is not appearing although it is being displayed in the terminal. I used `#{sharedBoards}` to display it in my Jade file. Can you guys please help me with this? I can't seem to find what is wrong.

Comment: Looks like your route is missing a comma after `passportConf.isAuthenticated`?

Comment: I just checked it, there is a comma there. I missed it here while writing it here. EDIT  i have updated the snippet above with the comma.

Comment: No one to help me out ? I'm sure it must be some thing silly

Comment: Where is your render code for the Jade file?

Comment: what do you mean by render code ? Sorry I'm quite new to this stack.

Comment: Where are you specifying your Jade file within your route? Typically it's `res.render('jadeFile'...)`

Comment: oh goodness! thanks I got it now. I mistyped sharedBoards in the render. I put it as shareBoards. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you can add your original render function to the question & put your fix as an answer, that would help this question be more useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.getBoards = function(req, res) {

Room.find({
    users: req.user._id
}, function(
    err,
    rooms) {
    if (err) {
        return err;
    }


        res.render('account/dashboard', {
            rooms: rooms,
                            count:req.count,
                            sharedBoards:req.sharedBoards
        });

});

 };
```

I mispelled sharedBoards.